# Completely block access to Cisco

Tags: security, cisco, vlan, access-control-list

There is Cisco Catalyst 3850 (WS-C3850-48T-E) which is managed only 
via management port.

There are several VLANs on the switch. Also the switch works as a DHCP server.

SNMP & SSH are already configured in terms of security. But, for example, 
the port is open for SNMPv3 on all interfaces that makes it susceptible 
to IP spoofing or DoS.

The issue is to completely block access to the switch services (except DHCP)
on the non-management interface.

If I understand correctly I can use Extended ACL. Something like that:

permit udp any host 10.11.12.1 eq 67

permit udp any host 10.11.13.1 eq 67

deny ip any host 10.11.12.1

deny ip any host 10.11.13.1

10.11.12.1 and 10.11.13.1 are IPs assigned to the current switch in the VLAN.

Is it correct approach? Will it work?

Comment: `But, for example, the port is open for SNMPv3 on all interfaces that makes it susceptible to IP spoofing or DoS` - I don't understand this statement. A user can't read or write via SSH or SNMP to a `port` on the switch. A user would need to know and connect to the management ip address, know the SSH password and kmow the SNMP community strings for the applicable SNMP communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All cisco ACL are ended with implicit "deny any any" rule. So you can configure only access-list extended to permit only required packets.

This approach will work in terms of blocking access.

It also good approach not to use VLAN 1 for anything in your network and configure separate VLAN for management only.